# Frequency divider circuit of a factor of arbitrary number

Tags: frequency, flipflop, counter, sequential-logic

We know that using T-Flip Flops in a cascaded manner(something like ripple counter) allows us to divide the clock frequency by a factor of \$2^{n}\$ where \$n\$ stands for the number of flip-flops. Now, Suppose I want to divide my original clock frequency by a factor of 3 or by 9? What can I do to achieve this?

My progress: Suppose we want to divide the given frequency by a factor of 6. Then, I thought that we can achieve our task by connecting the counter circuit and then adding some combinatorial circuit to change the clock only when 3 counts are done. This way whenever 6 counts are completed, one output cycle will complete.(Look at the circuit below):

[image]

But how do we do when we want to divide the clock frequency by a factor of 3 or 5 or 9?

Comment: If you don't care about duty cycle, just toggle after 2 counts, then after 3 counts, then 2 counts again and so on. This will divide the frequency by 5. For this, you will need not only a combinatorial circuit, but a memory element also (a flip flop?) to keep track of whether the current count limit should be 2 or 3.

Comment: Suppose we want to have a factor of 3. Then?

Comment: Like whenever three clock cycles complete, my one output cycle will complete.

Comment: For three use 1 count and 2 count alternately ?

Comment: Okay. But I think we won't be able to maintain a duty cycle of 50% then. Right?

Comment: Since it was an odd number you couldn't have anyway(*).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110885/discussion-between-puneet-and-ajn).

Comment: Read about , how do fractional -N synthesizers work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use added logic to capture counts as they appear at the binary counters outputs. The LSB is 1 if high. The weight of the bits is 1, 2, 4, 8 for a 4 bit counter. A count of 9 means 1 and 8 are high, 2 and 4 are low. Use and or nand gates on these pins to reset the counter each time it has a count of 9, or a count of 8 if asynchronous reset, as 0 is part of the count.

As long as the clock pulse is running it will repeat the same  count endlessly.

Because 0 is part of the count,  the counter will have one more state then the counters value.

Comment: This is correct. But I wanted to divide my clock frequency by arbitrary number. From your explanation. From what I understand, your suggestion would yield an answer which would have double the required time period.

Comment: For example I want my output to have a duty cycle of 50% and when three clock cycles complete, then one output cycle should complete.

Comment: To make a counter have an arbitrary value feedback is mandatory. If you have time constraints then double speed the clock.

Comment: Okay. Doubling the speed of the clock will work(given we can do that). By the way, I am new to electronics, what is arbitrary value feedback?

Comment: 50% duty cycle is impossible for odd numbers, unless you use a FF to divide by 2 to get 50%.

Comment: I recently read that Johnson's counter can be used to divide the clock signal by 3 or 5 in these references [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_6.html) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-bit-johnson-counter-in-digital-logic/). Can you give some insight how it can be done?

Comment: **Disadvantages of Johnson counter:**
Johnson counter doesn’t count in a binary sequence.
In Johnson counter more number of states remain unutilized than the number of states being utilized. For 'n' counts you need 'n' stages. Use a digital selector to set loopback point. Not as efficient as binary counters at all.

Comment: Unfortunately CiruitLab does not offer FF with both Q and Q\ outputs or complete binary counters, so I cannot draw you useful circuits with arbitrary count values. One day I may have OrCad working again and then I can draw what I please.

Answer (score 2):

Your flip-flop divider is creating a binary counter: the input is the one's place, the first FF gives the next binary digit, etc.

The key is that this type of counter resets automatically, e.g. after 16 cycles using 3 FF's (4 bits).  You can also reset the counter earlier to create an arbitrary divider; if you enable a (synchronous) reset when that counter has a value of N-1, the top bit (that changes) will yield a rising edge every N cycles.

Note that this output will not have a 50% duty cycle, unless N is a power of 2.  You can improve this with some additional decoding, outputting a 1 (only) when the counter is N/2 or greater.  If N is odd, you will need something like a PLL to achieve 50%.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

*How to divide frequency by an arbitrary number?*

---

***Answer***

*By a octal or decade counter.*

[image: decade and octal counter]

---

***References***

(1) [CD 4017 CD4022 CMOS Frequency Counter Dividers - TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs027c/schs027c.pdf?ts=1595388384371&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

(2) [Digital Counters - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_(digital))

(3) [Ring Counter (Including Johnson Counter) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter)

(4) [Johnson Counter - Electronics Course](http://electronics-course.com/johnson-counter)

(5) [Robert Royce Johnson (Johnson Counter) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Royce_Johnson)

(6) [Robert Royce (Bob) Johnson - The Salt Lake Tribune](https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/saltlaketribune/obituary.aspx?n=robert-royce-johnson-bob&pid=179460451)

---

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful summary of division methods using only JK flipflops without other gates, published in 1968(!) as *"Gateless Scalers with J-K Flip-flops"* by P. A. Neeteson of Philips Central Application Laboratory, Eindhoven, Netherlands. The article is long out of print, but I obtained a photocopy through the British Library.